# Opsworks Apache is Setting Up on multiple layers

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Inside of the [AWS Opsworks Cookbooks Repository](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks) in the [mod_php5_apache2 cookbook](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/mod_php5_apache2), you'll find the following in [`recipes/php.rb`](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/mod_php5_apache2/recipes/php.rb) (stripped for clarity):

```
# setup Apache virtual host
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  include_recipe 'apache2::service'

  if deploy[:application_type] != 'php'
    Chef::Log.debug("Skipping mod_php5_apache2::php application #{application} as it is not an PHP app")
    next
  end

  web_app deploy[:application] do
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

This iterates over **all** the applications in `node[:deploy]` that are flagged as PHP apps and among other things, creates apache2 configurations (vhosts) for HTTP and HTTPS.

This presents an issue when running the *Setup* life-cycle event because Opsworks (the Chef run) will attempt to create configurations for everything in `node[:deploy]` object even if these configurations don't apply to the currently executing (Setting Up) instance, or layer.

I have a duck-tape solution which works: Overriding the provided `php.rb` in my own repository and adding a custom app-to-layer mapping dictionary at the top.

```
map = {
  "phpapp1" => "layer1_php_application",
  "phpapp2" => "layer2_custom",
  "phpapp3" => "layer3_custom" 
}

# setup Apache virtual host
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

  if node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include? map[application]
      ...
      include_recipe 'apache2::service'

        if deploy[:application_type] != 'php'
          Chef::Log.debug("Skipping mod_php5_apache2::php application #{application} as it is not an PHP app")
          next
        end

        web_app deploy[:application] do
          ...
        end
      ...
  end
end
```

But it feels really gross because I've bundled app and layer names directly into my recipes.

While the conf files present an issue in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, similar unwanted files can be found in `/var/srv/` and `/var/log/apache2`...

What's the best way to fix this without:

1. Devoting an entire cookbook to each layer?
2. Or, using a custom dictionary as above

Is there something on the node object I can use as a filter that I've missed? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried using Apps environment variables? Quick tip when using you need an identifier to know what app will deploy in the layer